# The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in

Tags: windows-8

I had a working Windows 8 system (built from scratch - not an upgrade) and it all worked for about a month, then one day I get the following message (at sign-in time):-

***The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in***

I have read a number of posts suggesting that one login with an alternative account with admin rights...I dont have such an account, but apparently there is an built-in admin account that just need to be enabled...so I went through the steps..
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrator-activate.htm

However, although the steps appeared to work, I still dont get the Administrator account as one of the available accounts to login with.

So I am stumped.....any ideas?